# No display after boot on windows laptop after update

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have a ASUS X5DC Series WIN7 Pentium laptop.

I was going about my business as per usual, and windows prompted me for an update.

I continued just browsing the web as usual, working on some spreadsheets and I get a prompt to reboot for the update to sucessfully install.

So it reboots, ASUS screen displays as usual, Windows 7 loading screen appears.

Then the windows noise happens (the noise that always happens when you turn the pc on)

But the display then dies. Its black, Nothing.

I cant tell you what update it was.

I turn it off by holding the power for 5 seconds, turn it on again. And the same symptoms occur. Over and over again!

Its obvious the screen isnt broken because it works on boot. Its just after the windows loading screen, it dies.

Can anybody help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try booting with a Windows Installation disc and then restoring the last restore point. This will undo the changes of the last update.

If this doesn't work, you can try to boot with [Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) or something similar. You should be able to launch a mini XP, with which you hopefully can restore a restore point as well. I'm not sure of this, but it should be possible.

Comment: The first method worked perfectly thanks! i didnt realise the windows disk could be used for such a thing! Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) This is generally the first thing to do when you can't access the OS itself, because of some bad updates or missing drivers/dll's.