# Laptop not starting up after windows update

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

My laptop freezes on a black screen, i.e., the screen turns off but doesn't come back on after installing new Windows update, Windows 7 SP1 is what I think is causing it.

I've run the Windows start up repair and it gave the reason of a "bad patch" as the cause of the problems.

I've reverted to a restore point just before I updated so it's working now. But what I'm wondering is how do I stop this from keeping on happening as I've tried to update it myself a few times before posting this, and the problem happened every time.

Thanks.

I've foound a question that is the same as mine but only gives the restore option, but no solution to the problem.

[No display after boot on windows laptop after update](https://superuser.com/questions/367499/no-display-after-boot-on-windows-laptop-after-update)

Comment: Which update exactly causing this problem?

Comment: After years of delaing with Windows, I'm of the strong opinion Windows updates don't break Windows, when it seems they have, it's actually them just revealing another problem.  Having said that, dumping 100 patches plus a Service Pack all at once doesn't always go so smoothly.  What is the full/exact error Startup Repair presents (including Problem Signatures, etc.)?  When you attempt to apply patches one at a time, how far do you get?

Comment: Short of any more info on the error message, try to isolate the problem as much as possible. Are you only installing the service pack or are you doing other updates as well? Try updating your graphics card drivers or trying an older version if you can, and then reapply the update. Can you boot into safe mode before the black screen?

Comment: @techie007 Its just the service pack that causes the problem, I can't remember the problem signature, it could have been 0xa (that's the only one that i can recall that wasn't 0x0). I looked up the update history and the only one thats failed is sp1

Comment: @Zorawar its just the service pack I'm updating

Comment: @ELSheepO: When you do the update, what do you see before the black screen? Does the system freeze before the reboot or after it; do you see your BIOS splash screen? If so, then try to boot into safe mode. Otherwise try changing your graphics driver before the update if you can and see what happens.

Comment: I see everything up to the windows loading screen, before the login is when the screen dies. I've checked the display adapter and it's up to date. There's no graphics card

Comment: @ELSheepO: In that case, before the windows logo comes up keep pressing F8 until you see a menu where you can enter safe mode. Select safe mode with networking and see if that boots up. If so, then try to see if you can find any driver conflicts in device manager. If there is hardware that you installed, try disconnecting that and see if the system boots up.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I refrain from doing any kind of driver updates that Windows update throws in the "Optional" area. I find these cause all sorts of driver issues that cause anything from no display or bluescreens.

Comment: there was optional ones thrown in with the sp1 update, but even when I've done them seperatly they done't cause any problems, its only when I install the sp that the display doesn't turn back on.